# Call a controller function in a seprate class in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I have three classes: `HelloApplication`, `HelloController` and `ExtraClass`.

`HelloApplication`: (basic boilerplate)

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        URL fxml = getClass().getResource("hello-view.fxml");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxml);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        ExtraClass extraClass = new
        extraClass.marketRate(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

`HelloController`:

```
public class HelloController {
    public Button welcomeButton;
    
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    public void setText(String string) {
        welcomeText.setText(string);
    }
}
```

`ExtraClass`:

```
public class ExtraClass {
    public void marketRate(int currentPrice) {
        String s = String.valueOf(currentPrice \* 1.05);
        HelloController helloController = new HelloController();
        helloController.setText(s);
    }
}
```

Now I get an error saying that `this.welcomeText` is `null`.

I understand that if I make a new controller it isnt the right one, it doesnt have the fxml loaded.

How can I make it work?

I've tried passing a controller to the `ExtraClass` and it works, but I want an approach without that.

Comment: I would be more appropriate for `ExtraClass` to generate events that the controller "observed" and made appreciate updates - think about it, why would `ExtraClass` be responsible for updating the UI in the first place?  Creating another instance of `HelloController` would simply disconnect the `ExtraClass` from the UI anyway.  Part of the job of `FXMLLoader` is to load the fxml and bind it to the controller, which you've simply curumvented

Comment: if i would like to notify my subscriber aka controller i think i would still need somehow to call this controller @MadProgrammer

Comment: No, you wouldn’t - or, at least, not directly. You’d provide a mechanism for the interested party to register/subscribe for events and then through that mechanism, generate events. Your ExtraClass would not care who they are notifying - think of a button - it doesn’t care who it’s notifying, it just notifies registered observers

Comment: So, instead, your controller would register itself as an observer to the ExtraClass

Comment: The duplicate demonstrates how to implement MadProgrammer's suggestions.

Comment: The premise of the question is odd.  "I tried passing a controller...but I want an approach without that."  If you want to access a member function of an object from another object, you have to pass a reference to the first object to the second object.  This is just basic programming and you can't avoid it.